# Can fruits replace vegetables?

Tags: nutrition

I have a very simple question: Can you replace vegetables with fruits in your diet? As in, eat no vegetables instead eat lots of fruit? I dislike vegetables, my body literally rejects them for some reason, not to mention I have very few types of vegetables available in the country I live in, but instead we have fruit.

Can you have a perfectly healthy diet with no vegetables but with fruits instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I not eat vegetables and just eat more fruit?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1940/can-i-not-eat-vegetables-and-just-eat-more-fruit)

Comment: Also http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4350/do-fruit-and-vegetable-provide-a-similar-health-benefit

Comment: @Dave Liepman, I'm new here, I didn't have time to search the site for duplicates, I did make a search first but I didn't find much.

Comment: No worries, I understand. Perhaps those questions help with this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the evidence I've seen - high-fruit diets are generally *not* healthy. Fructose is becoming more obvious as *not* being a "healthy" form of sugar.

[10 Reasons why Fructose is Bad](http://paleodietlifestyle.com/10-reasons-why-fructose-is-bad/)
[The Fructose Index is the new Glycemic Index](http://wholehealthsource.blogspot.com/2008/11/fructose-index-is-new-glycemic-index.html)
[Fructose versus Glucose](http://wholehealthsource.blogspot.com/2009/04/fructose-vs-glucose-showdown.html)

Note that those articles are generally talking about fructose added to other foods - fruit is slightly better, given that it has vitamins, fiber, and is absorbed slower than, say, a soft drink. Still, eating excessive amounts of fruit will give you lots of fructose, which isn't recommended.

Check out the books/articles at [another answer of mine](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/4955/1898) for some recommendations for good food plans. They generally include both meat and vegetables (and fish, and eggs...)

Disclaimer: As you will find on *any* question of diet/nutrition (or exercise, or politics, or...) - **there is no consensus**, no "right" answer. (Nor am I a doctor or nutritionist, this post not to be taken internally).

For an opposing view of how great fruit is - see [30 Bananas a Day](http://www.30bananasaday.com/).

Comment: I didn't actually plan to address this, but after the other answer...

Comment: Thanks. I do admit the other answer is... well, just plain dumb.

Comment: Fructose as an additive sugar is NOT HEALTHY. But eating fruits, which of course have fructose content, is not problematic, since it has lots of fibers.

Comment: @Jauzsika, fiber is helpful, as I *did* mention - but it doesn't magically make *all* the fructose disappear. At best, it raises the threshold on how much fructose you can safely consume. According to the first link, more than 100g of sugar from fruit a day, *would* be "problematic". Is it right? That's why I said there is no consensus. :) Some researchers think too much fructose (in any form, even fruit) is dangerous - others don't. Believe who you want to...

Comment: I believe in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBnniua6-oM